# App Rejected on 17.2 clause. Asking for email ID

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, privacy

My app is a sync solution (imagine dropbox).
The user needs to sign in to access the app's features, and if he does not have any account already created, he can sign up.

The sign up asks for email id verification, and this email id is also used if the user has forgotten his password to send him one.

but Apple has rejected this app saying:

> 17.2: Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and     date of birth, in order to function will be rejected
>
> We found that your app requires customers to register with personal information to access non-account-based features, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Apps cannot require user registration prior to allowing access to app features and content that are not associated specifically to the user. User registration that requires the sharing of personal information must be optional or tied to account-specific functionality. Additionally, the requested information must be relevant to the features.
>
> Although guideline 11.6 of the App Store Review Guidelines requires an application to make subscription content available to all the iOS devices owned by a single user, it is not appropriate to force user registration to meet this requirement; such user registration must be made optional.
>
> It would be appropriate to make it clear to the user that registering will enable them to access the content from any of their iOS devices, and to provide them a way to register at any time, if they wish to later extend access to additional iOS devices

Please help me solve this. Many apps like dropbox/facebook require login.
I don't get the exact reason why they rejected my app.

Also, please guide about the in app purchase, why registering cannot be mandatory

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Asked App Store Review people for clarification on their rejection.
They accepted it. and the app got approved :D
Its on Appstore now :)

Comment: Ha! Same exact scenario happened here. Just asked for clarification and within minutes they approved it. Good call @Nikita P.

Comment: did you re-upload the binary?

Comment: No. I appealed in the binary rejection, and asked for clarification.

Comment: how did you appealed? Whats the process, could you tell me. Yesterday I asked them the reason in detail and today they sent me this: `**Thank you for your message. It is inappropriate to force the users to log in or register before granting them access to the In App Purchases. It would be appropriate to revise the app so that users may subscribe without having to register or log in. We look forward to reviewing your revised app.**`. It is weird coz my earlier app hving same functions was accepted by them :(

Comment: okay, i think I should follow this: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/contact/?topic=appeal

Comment: yes, that's the correct link. If the reviewer does not agree. Try adding a description in Review Notes while submitting again. Hopefully you get a new reviewer, and he accepts.

Comment: I did, but they are still not approving it :(. I told them why previous app was approved, they are saying their might be a new guideline has come or any 'other reason'.

Comment: bad luck..some reviewers are very strict.

Comment: @NikitaP they are not accepting in all cases. but we should try for clarification or appeal.

Answer (score 5):

I also Faced this kind of Problem and my app also Rejected due to this.And Again I Changed my App flow Like User Registration will be Optional. User can See all the Feature of the app with out Registration by skipping this step.If he want to do something user-specific then you can ask to register such as : (user like,comment,photo upload etc) or else he can use the contents and features which are public.

in Case of in-app Purchase You can Prompt user that if He will Register with your app he can able to use this Content in his all devices.

It would be appropriate to make it clear to the user that registering will enable them to access the content from any of their iOS devices, and to provide them a way to register at any time, if they wish to later extend access to additional iOS devices

Answer (score 4):

Apple does not allow apps that require you to share person information to work, like an e-mail address.

You options are, remove the need for an e-mail address or remove account creation form you app and move it to a website.

It also states that you app is asking to create an account to access the full app and even needs the account or acces features that do not require the user to have an account. You can make those features available with out the account creating you might be able to get thru the review.

The reason apps like Facebook and Dropbox got thru the review proces is because they don't have a register option which is in app only. They redirect to a website.

Comment: And what about instagram, they follow registration process and than to they got through the review process??

Comment: Well it is up to the review to allow or deny your app. But in the AppStore guidelines it clearly states: `: Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth, in order to function will be rejected`

Comment: @rckoenes: Which is a stupid guideline. Apple removes all identifiers (like hardware IDs, etc.) to make a device identifyable, so other identifiers (like an email adress) are required. I personally had to make an app for a customer which requires the date of birth and email address in order to function, because this it is used for his/her analysis (calculation) which is send to his/her email. With this guidelinese Apple makes it impossible, because... yeah, why? It is confidential user data which needs to be protected somehow.

Answer (score 3):

I recently spoke to an Apple Rep over the phone in regards to an app of mine that was also accused of violating clause 17.2.

I explained to him that the email would be used for password recovery, monitoring transactions within the marketplace, and managing any inappropriate behavior (such as users uploading offensive or copyrighted content). The rep responded, "Sir, the clause states 'Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth, in order to function will be rejected'. I cannot allow you to require your users to submit their emails if its not account-based". He did not seem to understand that the emails are account-based for the very sole purpose of security.

I did mention to him that Instagram and Facebook alike require logins at startup. He simply replied, "Yes but those apps are entirely account-based."

Honestly, I felt he was blindly following Apple's Guidelines ("Because that's what it says we must strictly follow!"). He had little understanding of how social networking apps operate, and even less understanding of the law (specifically the DMCA - on a separate issue). Explaining to them how all that works proves to be futile; they wont budge because they are asked to follow Apple's BROAD Clauses as strictly as they do.

My conclusion: I had to compromise the app's user flow such that the app's registration page can be skipped, and all other functions within its marketplace were locked to non-registered users. It makes no sense.

Comment: otherwise you can give a tutorial before going to your registration page and  explain clearly why someone requires an account before proceeding

Answer (score 1):

> The sign up asks for email id verification, and this email id is also used if the user has forgotten his password to send him one.
>
> Apps cannot require user registration prior to allowing access to app features and content that are not associated specifically to the user.

It seems to me that the point is that you are asking the user to provide his email address as a step towards the creation of a user account. This is different from what dropbox and other apps do (i.e, you provide your credentials for your dropbox account, which is different from your email address, although it can be the same).

You may either remove altogether email verification, or you could postpone it to a later point when you have made clear to the user that this is required to access private information.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same thing last week and this is Apple's reply:

> As for the 17.2 issue, a nickname, avatar, or sharing are not inherent or specific features of those social networks, and thus, the user should not be required to register with those services, or provide you with access to their social network accounts. The user should not be prevented from using your app and service if they do not provide this information.
>
> Instead, it would be appropriate use your own authentication method and give users the option to create a nickname and upload an avatar, independent from those networks.
>
> Moreover, we realize that these social networks may be very popular. However, the popularity of the social network is not an appropriate reason to force a user who has not, or chose not to register and provide their personal information to those services, before they can use your app.
>
> Therefore, we ask that you to include your own authentication mechanism to allow the user the option to register only with you, creating an account with only the information needed and relevant to your app's features.
>
> Best regards,
>
> App Store Review

So in short, you have to provide custom authentication and not just use Facebook. Although I've seen many Apps who do require you to login with Facebook.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 1):

It happened same for me, although the first version was approved, the second version was rejected for this reason, I added the Skip button at the landing view.

Answer (score -2):

It's all summarized in the last paragraph. Apparently, your application doesn't inform the user (in a clear way) that registering is for syncing and from their reply, it seems that your application is useless without the Sign Up.

If that's the case, you should be more specific why you need the user to register.

On a side note, I personally don't like the applications/websites that force you to register before you see or try anything. I hope your application isn't the same.

Comment: but a user-data-sync-solution needs to be user specific. Take Dropbox into account. How can you give any feature which is not user specific. (for example, syncing files)