# Non-renewing IAP registration form: Is it allowed to ask for personal information?

Tags: in-app-purchase, user-registration, non-renewing-subscription

My app features a non-renewing subscription (In-App Purchase). Registration is optional but recommended. Currently I ask for an email address and a password. Apple gave its ok to that.

Has anybody experience in whether it's allowed to ask for more than that? E.g. first/last name, company, phone number (may even be optional)?

---

Edit: I've updated my app to ask for additional registration data, but only the company, an email address and a password are mandatory. I don't know whether the reviewer overlooked this change in the app or if it's ok to do so, but it passed the review.

Comment: I don't have experience, but I think you can ask, but just don't require it. With your developer account, take a look at https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html (see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13561238/app-rejected-on-17-2-clause-asking-for-email-id).

Answer (score 0):

my previous app was approved but they rejected 2nd app which is following same login and registration process. Here is the 1st reaction I got from them:

> 17.2
>
> We found that your app requires customers to register with personal
> information to access non-account-based features, which is not in
> compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Although guideline 11.6 of the App Store Review Guidelines requires an
> application to make subscription content available to all the iOS
> devices owned by a single user, it is not appropriate to force user
> registration to meet this requirement; such user registration must be
> made optional.
>
> It would be appropriate to make it clear to the user that registering
> will enable them to access the content from any of their iOS devices,
> and to provide them a way to register at any time, if they wish to
> later extend access to additional iOS devices.

Again i opted for a clarification on the rejection with my comment that previous app was approved, then they replied this:

> **Reasons**
>
> **17.2: Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth, in order to function will be rejected**
>
> Thank you for your message. Users must have an option to purchase
> subscriptions without being forced to register and log in.
>
> On occasion, there may be apps on the App Store that don't appear to
> be in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines - they may have
> been approved before the current Guidelines were available or for
> other reasons. We work hard to ensure that the apps on the App Store
> are in compliance and we try to identify any apps currently on the App
> Store that may not be. It takes time to identify these occurrences but
> another app being out of compliance is not a reason for your app to
> be.
>
> It would be appropriate to revise your other app so that it would also
> be in compliance with the Guidelines. We look forward to reviewing
> your revised apps.

Now I am trying to connect with them on phone, let's see what happens. But it is really weird. :(

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. I've updated my question too with mine.